# Save avro multiple times in the same path using Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using [databrick spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) (for `Spark 1.5.5.2`) for saving a DataFrame fetched from ElasticSearch as Avro into HDFS. After I have done some processing on my DataFrame, I save the data on HDFS using the following command:

```
df.write.avro("my/path/to/data")
```

Everything works fine and I can read my data using Hive. The biggest issue I'm facing, at the time, is that I can't write twice data into the same path (running my script twice with `"my/path/to/data"` as output, for example). As long as I need to add data incrementally, how can I solve this problem? I thought some workarounds, like

- Changing the output directory every day (creating a partitioning), or
- Saving the data in a tmp folder and then insert them into a "main" table

But I wonder if I can find a way to actually solve this problem on Spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide an appropriate mode. Overwrite if you want to replace existing data:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").avro("my/path/to/data")
```

append if you want to add:

```
df.write.mode("append").avro("my/path/to/data")
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Sorry for the trivial question, I just started working with Spark

Answer (score 3):

If your data is not frequently updated the Append works fine as

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).avro("outputpath")
```

If you are frequently updating then it creates a large number of files (it may be empty files too)
To overcome this issue you need to

- Read previous data and append to it
- Store in temporary directory
- Delete original directory and
- Rename temporary directory to original

Hope this helps